# Is npx react-native link a working command?

Tags: node.js, react-native, getstream-io

I am following [(https://getstream.io/blog/slack-clone-with-stream-chat-part-1/)](https://getstream.io/blog/slack-clone-with-stream-chat-part-1/) and it is telling me to run

```
npx react-native link
```

But when I do I receive `error: unknown command 'link'`

After reading online I see I need to run `npx react-native-asset` instead. However, that is giving me

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/yonahfeld/places/ios/places/react-native.config.js'
Require stack:
- /Users/yonahfeld/.npm/_npx/545c366a5ae830a2/node_modules/react-native-asset/lib/cli.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yonahfeld/.npm/_npx/545c366a5ae830a2/node_modules/react-native-asset/lib/cli.js:45:27)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/yonahfeld/.npm/_npx/545c366a5ae830a2/node_modules/react-native-asset/lib/cli.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.11.0
```

Comment: Hi Yona, I’m getting the right people involved internally. I’m working on getting an answer to you in the next 24h.

Answer (score 1):

This blog is outdated and is only compatible with an old version (v2) of the React Native Chat SDK. This blog will be archived to prevent future confusion. Please check our latest [tutorial](https://getstream.io/chat/react-native-chat/tutorial/#setup-up-test-channels-and-test-users-optional) or our finished [Slack clone](https://github.com/GetStream/react-native-samples/tree/develop/projects/SlackClone#slack-clone-using-react-native-and-stream-chat)